# ESXi 6.5 web client mutual SSL authentication

Tags: ssl, vmware-esxi, certificate

Has anyone done it? Don't like the idea of relying exclusively on a user and password.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ESXi (at least up to 6.5, I don't have personal experience with 6.7 yet) has no support for authentication with client certificates.

The closest you can get would be smart card authentication when you configure your ESXi to join an Active Directory.

[image]

Smart card authentication is available since 6.0 IIRC.

---

To add another layer of security, you can place the management network of your ESXi hosts into a VLAN that is only reachable by your administrators. The firewall can also be helpful here.